# Decrypt file with salt/password created in C# in Java

Tags: java, encryption

I have a file which was encrypted with this code (C# code that was used to encrypt):

```
public static byte[] AES_Encrypt(byte[] bytesToBeEncrypted, byte[] passwordBytes)
    {
        byte[] encryptedBytes = null;

        // Set your salt here, change it to meet your flavor:
        // The salt bytes must be at least 8 bytes.
        byte[] saltBytes = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (RijndaelManaged AES = new RijndaelManaged())
            {
                AES.KeySize = 256;
                AES.BlockSize = 128;

                var key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passwordBytes, saltBytes, 1000);
                AES.Key = key.GetBytes(AES.KeySize / 8);
                AES.IV = key.GetBytes(AES.BlockSize / 8);

                AES.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

                using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, AES.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cs.Write(bytesToBeEncrypted, 0, bytesToBeEncrypted.Length);
                    cs.Close();
                }
                encryptedBytes = ms.ToArray();
            }
        }

        return encryptedBytes;
    }
```

I have the password and am trying to decrypt in java but having trouble understanding how to do this in java as compared to C#.   There are libraries in C# which I could decrypt this with but I need to do this in java.  The file to be decrypted is a csv file.

So far from searches online and some other work this i what i have so far. If i put in any string in place of "encryptedString" I can decrypt just fine.  So i am guessing my approach is incorrect and i should just be decrypting the file instead of the string of what the file turns into.  How can this be accomplished though.  I have some code here which also takes the file itself, turns it into a byte array and then tries to decrypt that in place of the bytes of a string. Also not getting a decryption to work on this.  If anyone can help me out here it would be very helpful.

My java code:

```
File encryptedFile = getFileTodecrypt();
    byte[] salt = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
    SecretKeyFactory factory =     SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
    KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(PASSWORD.toCharArray(), salt, 1000, 256);
    SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
    SecretKey secret = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");

    /* Encrypt the message. */
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret);

    AlgorithmParameters params = cipher.getParameters();
    byte[] iv = params.getParameterSpec(IvParameterSpec.class).getIV();

    File fileToDecrypt = getFileTodecrypt(); // this gets my file
    InputStream inputStream = FileUtils.openInputStream(fileToDecrypt);
    byte[] bytesToBeDecrypted = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);

    // file bytes does not work
    //byte[] ciphertext = cipher.doFinal(bytesToBeDecrypted);
    // file to string does not work
    //byte[] ciphertext = cipher.doFinal(encryptedString.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    // this works, but does not take c# code into account at all
    byte[] ciphertext = cipher.doFinal("hello".getBytes("UTF-8"));

    IvParameterSpec iv2 = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

    //decrypt
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secret, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
    String plaintext = new String(cipher.doFinal(ciphertext), "UTF-8");
    System.out.println(plaintext);

}

private String convertFileToString(File encryptedFile) throws IOException {
    String fileString = FileUtils.readFileToString(encryptedFile, "UTF-8");
    return fileString;

}
```

Comment: I don't have time to look into how to decrypt it for you. I am just going to suggest using bouncy castle instead of the java built in to handle what you are trying to do. https://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html

Comment: Thanks for the direction, i will try.

Comment: Not having a ton of luck, although im starting to understand crypto stuff better.  Still cant seem to get my code to work.